# Cyclic subgroups of same order of a non cyclic group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Suppose $G$ is a group that is NOT cyclic.
Let $H$ and $K$ be its cyclic subgroups of the same order.

Then is it true that:
Either $H = K$ or $H \cap K = \{e\}$.

If yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the quaternion group $H_8=\{\pm1,\pm i,\pm j,\pm k\}$.
Try $H=\left<i\right>$ and $K=\left<j\right>$.

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to understand your example.

Comment: @AJ_ $H=\{1,i,-1,-i\}$ and $K=\{1,j,-1,-j\}$ both are cyclic groups of order $4$ with non-trivial intersection.

Comment: But in this case H8 is also cyclic right?

Comment: @AJ_ No, you can try to check that this group has no element of order $8$ and therefore is non-cyclic.

Comment: So the conclusion is: my proposition is false? And that H intersect K can be non trivial, right?

Comment: @AJ_ Yes. You are right.